# Recorrido infinito al usar bucle while

Tags: javascript

```
 let nombre= lol
while ((nombre != "lola") || (nombre != "lila") || (nombre !="lilo"))   
{nombre = prompt ("elige entre lola lila y lilo") }
```

/* estoy intentando hacer un bucle en el que una persona debe elegir entre los nombres lola lila y lilo. Se supone que se le debe preguntar un nombre hasta que la respuesta sea una de las tres opciones. El problema es que hace la pregunta, pero aunque la respuesta sea lola lila o lilo, sigo dentro del bucle. */

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Me parece tienes una estructura errónea respecto al uso del `while`, pues:

- Deberías tener alguna comparación de cumplimiento o incumplimiento en tu `while`, es decir:

  - `true === false`
  - `i < contador`
  - etc.
- Por dentro del mismo entonces realizar alguna comparativa de los valores ingresados por el usuario
- Pudieras declarar una bandera que este en `false` mientras el usuario no escriba un nombre de las opciones y que cambie a `true` cuando el nombre sea una opción correcta

**Ejemplo**

```js
    let nombreCorrecto = false
    do{
      let nombre = prompt("Ingresa tu nombre")
      
      if(nombre === "uno" || nombre === "dos" || nombre === "tres") {
        console.log("Bien")
        nombreCorrecto = true
      }else {
        console.log("Mal")
      }
      
    }while(nombreCorrecto === false)
```

- Entonces hacemos uso de un `do while` para que al menos una vez si se ejecuten los bloques de código antes de la condición
- Por dentro comparamos con un `if else` si el valor que el usuario ingresa por `prompt` corresponde a alguna opción
- Si el nombre es alguno de los listados, entonces convertimos la variable a `true`

Si el nombre es acertado, en consola debe devolver entonces `bien true`

Comment: Muchísimas gracias !!